# "'x' must be a non-empty numeric vector" rpy2 error: why is it not working?

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, pandas

I am using Colab and Python to find the best fit distribution for my data. I am a newbie in this, so am experiencing a lot of problems. So far, here's my code:

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

MASS = importr('MASS')
pandas2ri.activate()

df_temp = pd.DataFrame()
df_temp["Values"] = [37.50,46.79,48.30,46.04,43.40,39.25]
ri_temp = pandas2ri.py2ri(df_temp)

params_temp = MASS.fitdistr(ri_temp, 'normal')
print(params_temp)
```

Now, there is a lot going on that I don't understand yet. Please be as descriptive as possible!:) For instance, I am not getting the idea of why I have to use `pandas2ri.activate()`. The error that my code is producing is this:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146:
  RRuntimeWarning: Error in (function (x, densfun, start, ...)  : 

  'x' must be a non-empty numeric vector
```

... Traceback in between...

```
warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
  RRuntimeError: Error in (function (x, densfun, start, ...)  : 

  'x' must be a non-empty numeric vector
```

So, what's the issue?

The reason I am using pandas first is that I have my data stored in a list. If I can avoid using pandas, then what would be the alternative? When I tried simply parsing `MASS.fitdistr(list, 'normal')` it gives me errors as well. Also, maybe there is a better alternative to using r to find the best fit distribution for a given list data? Any recommendations?

Comment: Please check your `ri_temp`  I guess it is a `data.frame`, while the `fitdistr`, x should be `vector`

Answer (score 0):

This helped: `my_array = np.asarray(my_list)`. And then using the array as my input for: `params_temp = MASS.fitdistr(my_array, 'normal')`.

Thanks to akrun.